# Is there a way I can do something different on the last iteration of an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<td>
    <span data-ng-repeat="question in row.questions">{{ question.questionId }},</span>
</td>
```

This iterates through row.questions and gives an output looking like:

```
1,2,3,
```

My problem is with the last comma.  Is there something that I could do to prevent the last comma from appearing. Note that I am currently using the 1.15 but if there was something new in the 1.2rc that would help I would be okay to use that.

Here is the HTML I currently have with the suggested solution:

```
    <tr data-ng-show="grid.data.length > 0" data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data | orderBy:problemSortField.key:inverse">
      <td>{{ row.problemId }}</td>
      <td>
         <span data-ng-repeat="question in row.questions">
            {{ question.questionId }}<span data-ng-if="$last">,</span>
         </span> 
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$last`:

```
<td>
    <span data-ng-repeat="question in row.questions">
        {{ question.questionId }}<span ng-if="!$last">,</span>
    </span>     
</td>
```

**NOTE:** `ngIf` is a new directive added in v1.1.5.

Comment: Interestingly this does not work "217, 218, 219, 217 218 219" and "33, 34, 33 34" etc.  I copied your code exactly.

Comment: Can you edit your question to share the model data and how you have used $last inside the HTML?

Comment: I copied your latest and now getting "9, 12," etc

Comment: @Melina I have been acting like a stupid. Please recheck my answer :D

Comment: I am sorry. I just checked and I am using 1.14. I will change and report back. Thanks for all of your help with this. Will update in a few mins.

Comment: @Melina Just make sure that you do `ng-if="!$last"` and not `ng-if="$last"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works great now. I'm lucky they added the ng-if .. As usual AngularJS saves the day !